# cron resource not working in aws opswork?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I've this script in my recipe

```
cron "logs_processPageView" do
  minute "*"
  hour "*"
  day "*"
  month "*"
  weekday "*"
  command %Q{
    echo "hi" >> /home/ubuntu/test.txt
  }
  action :create
end
```

When I run the recipe with opswork, here is the corresponding log

```
[Fri, 12 Jul 2013 02:42:48 +0000] DEBUG: Processing cron[logs_processPageView] on test1.localdomain
[Fri, 12 Jul 2013 02:42:48 +0000] DEBUG: Cron 'logs_processPageView' not found
[Fri, 12 Jul 2013 02:42:48 +0000] INFO: Added cron 'logs_processPageView'
```

{code}

I assumed the cron have been added to the cron job.

But when I ssh'd to the instance, there is no test.txt, even if I wait an hour. Also there is no new cronjob when I run {code}sudo crontab -l{code} or {code}crontab -l{code}.

Why the resource not adding the cronjob?

I tried to use [cron cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/cron). There is new file in /etc/cron.d/cronfile, but the cron still not working.

What did I've done wrong? And how to fix it?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Logs shows cron has been added, but "contab -l" show no cron jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug because opswork was using Chef 9 (very outdated Chef).

Currently they have already upgraded to Chef 11.4, so you can try again, because my script in the question now is working.